# Analogous tensor product operation for reflexive sheaf

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, birational-geometry, coherent-sheaves, several-complex-variables

Suppose now $(X,\mathcal O_X)$ is a normal complex space, and $\mathcal F$ is a coherent analytic sheaf on it.

Product the reflexive sheaf $$\mathcal F^{[p]}:=(\mathcal F^{\otimes p})^{**},$$ where $\mathcal G^{**}:=\text{Hom}_{\mathcal O_X}(\text{Hom}_{\mathcal O_X}(\mathcal G,\mathcal O_X),\mathcal O_X)$ denotes the  double dual of some coherent sheaf $\mathcal G$.

Here is my possibly trivial question: do the following relationship

$$(\mathcal F^{[p]})^{[q]}=\mathcal F^{[pq]}$$

hold?

Any comments and references would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes: Let $U$ be the maximal open set where $\mathcal{F}^{**}$ is locally free. The equation you want holds on $U$. Now use the  extension of locally free sheaf from $U$ to a reflexive sheaf on $X$ is unique because the space is normal.

Comment: Thanks @DonuArapura.